# SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS ) - is it possible to format all gridlines at once in the report?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Is it possible to format all charts at once. For example, I want to set all charts with the same background color, remove all grid lines, set x axis font to x size etc.

I know I can do it manually, but I would like to "pre configure" so all charts are the same. There must be something to put in the **code** section

Many thanks

SOLVED:
I have created a template. You can put your templates in the folders below:

**For SQL Server 2008**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject

**For SQL Server 2012**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject

Comment: The .rdl files are cleanly formatted XML. You can use a text editor or the scripting/programming of your choice to do search & replace/add. Get one chart formatted the way you like and then start copying properties.

Comment: Create a template report and use that template for all reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template report in reporting services and re-use this template across all of your reports.

I wrote this blog post a long long time ago but it should work for 2003, 2005, 2008 and 2012: See this: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jhermiz/archive/2007/08/14/60283.aspx

Answer (score 0):

no, the code is unique per report.

What you can do is create an External assembly with your code and access it on all your reports to change run-time properties.

Comment: I know it is beyond the scope of this question; however, I have zero knowledge about external assemblies. Please can you provide where is the best place to start working on it. (e.g. book or video blog) Many thanks

Comment: take a look at this: https://dmenin.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/custom-codessrs-2008/